# Cannot sign my ios application with distribution profile

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode4.3, provisioning-profile

I've generated distribution provisioning profile for my ios app, but I cannot sign my application with it, I get this error:

profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

The developer certificates works well, I can upload my apps to my tests devices,

but I've noticed this warning for distribution profile: Valid Signing identity not found

Can this be a source of my problems for distribution provisioning profile or is this expected warning?

[image]

and I suspect that it forbid me from signing the app for the app store upload

[image]

I'm pretty sure that I've made all my bundle (app?) identifiers consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sets of public and private keys you need to have in your keychain.

One of them will be prefixed with "iPhone Developer:" and the other "iPhone Distribution:".

Make sure ***both*** are in your keychain by opening the Keychain Access application within your "`/Application/Utilities`" folder.  If you don't see both, then there's your problem (and you'll need to import your keys from another machine that does have the keys installed).

Answer (score 0):

Don't Lose you keys!

If you bought a new computer and did not export your keys and you don't have the computer your S.O.L. you have to start the process all over again.